# PHP7.3 upgrade from php5.6 and wordpress backend slow

Tags: php7

Recently i upgraded my dedicated server

from php-fmp 5.6 to 7.3
mysql from 5.5 to 5.7

Frontend is really fast...but backend is drammatically slow!

If i run a long processo like a revision of some product (i use woocommerce), this process make busy all backend and i cant open another chrome task that return a blank page.

Is there something wrong? I don't changed my configuration...only opgraded

ps mysql, php and nginx log are all empty...no error only some advice...

Comment: I don't known about wordpress specifics, but may be php configured to not show warnings and notices in error log. Try `error_reporting = E_ALL` in php.ini and check logs for warning and notices, may be find something usefull. Or may be problem in mysql, some slow sql statements executing. Search for 'mysql show queries' to enable log and find out slow queries. Its not clear what exactly you mean with backend, php, mysql?

Comment: i mean backend of wordpress not php or mysql. But problem has gone after upgrading. Before all fast

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the OPcache by uncommenting the following line in `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini`, or `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini` depending on if you use FPM or `mod_php`:

```
;opcache.enable=1
```

followed by restarting Apache or php-fpm.

Even if OPcache was enabled in the previous version of PHP, it would not transfer over to 7.3 because it uses a different configuration file.